# Can nested undefined behavior(s) cancel the (potential) hazard of the initial undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, c, undefined-behavior

In case of nested undefined behaviors:

1. Can one of the subsequent undefined behavior lead to canceling the (potential) hazard of the initial undefined behavior?
2. Can the combination of all the subsequent undefined behaviors lead to canceling the (potential) hazard of the initial undefined behavior?

Is there are an examples from practice showing a canceling (by coincidence) the hazard of the initial undefined behavior due to the presence of nested undefined behavior(s)?

Comment: No. Undefined behaviour is undefined, anything can happen including what you describe.

Comment: By definition, in case of UB, implementations are allowed to destroy the Universe, restart Sens8 on Netflix and prove that P=NP by induction.

Comment: If you have a certain clearly *defined* way to counter undefined behavior, it wouldn't be **undefined**, would it. If you were to write your own compiler and you added some code into it which detects certain types of UB (like say when you return a pointer to a local reference) and if it does it aborts the rest of the execution and instead starts a game of Tetris, it would still be a valid C++ compiler. Doing that is allowed within the specifications of the language.

Comment: Why would it? If you have UB1: "if running around on the highway you might get hit by a car" and UB2: "running around with a plastic bag over your head might cause you to choke", then how exactly would "running around on the highway with a plastic bag over your head" suddenly be safe? It's very likely the exact opposite.

Comment: Might want to read up on [What is undefined behavior and how does it work?](https://software.codidact.com/questions/277486).

Comment: Once you go undefined, your whole program stays undefined until termination

Answer (score 3):

You are thinking about undefined behaviour wrong. Its not "something that has happened and you can analyse what". Its "your program no longer has any guarantees, it may seem to work now. It may not. It may work only if the moon is full. It may start working when you change compilers. It may fail to work on a different OS.". No matter how many instances of undefined behaviour you have, they cannot cancel each other out. UB + UB is *always* UB.

Once you have UB anything can happen including it happening to work. This is true no matter how many instances of UB you had in the original source.

However, taking a compiled binary that was generated by a code base that had undefined behaviour and analysing what that binary does *is* possible and you can easily find places where 2 wrongs cancel each other out. Probably the simplest example would be overwriting the end of an array onto another variable which you forgot to initialise. I've actually seen this one happen.

Note that if you do this, you still dont have any guarantees that its "ok". If you upgrade compilers or perturb the system in anyway (even if you just recompile) then next time the compiler may choose to layout things differently resulting in a new binary which doesn't work.

Comment: Re “Once you have UB anything can happen”: You are thinking about undefined behavior wrong. It is not “anything can happen.” It is “The language standard does not define what can happen.” By analogy, consider languages to be US states, like Colorado or Wyoming. Colorado’s laws may say what happens while you are in Colorado’s jurisdiction. Outside of Colorado’s jurisdiction, they **do not** say what happens, but they **cannot** give permission for anything to happen. For example, Colorado cannot say you are allowed to steal things in Wyoming…

Comment: … So the C or C++ standard cannot say your program may violate the hardware specification; they cannot grant permission for “anything” to happen. This is a significant difference because many programmers work beyond the C or C++ standards; they deliberately use behaviors that are defined by other specifications, such as the specific C implementation, the operating system, the hardware, and so on. For example, to use graphic user interfaces, you must use features that are not defined by the C standard, so you must rely on those working; it would not be acceptable if anything could happen.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Your analogy regarding "jurisdiction" isn't the best; it would be better if it involved e.g. a state's laws and the policies of a company that's within the state.  Some states likely have laws that would forbid a hotel from simply re-hanging towels left on the floor by one guest before renting the room to another, while other states might not, but even in states that don't, people who are renting rooms at anything other than the most bargain-basement hotels should generally expect clean towels.  An important thing to note is that some standards, including the C Standard,...

Comment: ...deliberately allow implementations intended for specialized purposes to behave in ways that are tailored for some narrow tasks, but make them unsuitable for most others; such allowance is in no way intended to suggest that quality general-purpose implementations shouldn't behave in ways appropriate to most tasks without regard for whether the Standard would require them to do so.

Comment: @EricPostpischil In your analogy, you can still steal things in Wyoming, and Colorado has nothing to do with it. Colorado does not have jurisdiction over Wyoming. Anything can happen in Wyoming, and Colorado's laws are not violated. That is what "Anything can happen" means .

Comment: @M.M: By “Anything can happen in Wyoming, and Colorado's laws are not violated,” you appear to mean, using more precise terminology, “If some thing happens in Wyoming, it does not violate Colorado’s laws.” That statement does not imply that anything can happen in Wyoming. Further, if that is not what you meant, then you are using “Anything can happen in Wyoming” as a premise to conclude “Anything can happen [in Wyoming, when behavior is undefined, whatever].” In that case, it is invalid reasoning. The analogy stands: Colorado’s laws do not say anything can happen in Wyoming.

Comment: @EricPostpischil They imply it by omission since they do not cover. Maybe there is a language difficulty here? It is in the same sense as "Anything can happen and I'll be fine" , i.e. a universal quantifier , not some kind of assertion about the set of realistic eventualities.

Comment: @M.M: The difference is not between whether something can happen or cannot happen. The difference is between making an assertion and not making an assertion. The laws of Colorado **do not assert** that “anything can happen” in Wyoming. That is not saying things cannot happen. It is a lack of any assertion at all. So asserting the laws of Colorado mean “anything can happen” in Wyoming is incorrect. Similarly, for undefined behavior, the C standard **does not assert** that “anything can happen.”

Comment: @EricPostpischil "anything can happen" is a universal quantifier, not an assertion. "The standard says anything can happen" has the same meaning as "For all X, the standard does not prohibit X from happening".

Comment: @M.M: No, a quantifier is a modifier describing the number of things something applies to, like “for each.” “Anything can happen” is a full sentence: noun and verb; it is an assertion. And it is one that misleads students. Often Stack Overflow pundits tell people that this wrong definition of undefined behavior, that “anything can happen,” means there is **nothing** that can be deduced or relied on. That is false. The C standard’s “undefined behavior” means only that nothing from it provides anything to deduce or rely on.

Comment: @EricPostpischil "for all" statements can be changed to logically equivalent "for each" statements (with appropriately placed negations) and vice versa . See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_quantification . It does not even make sense to assert "anything can happen" , what are you trying to say with such an assertion?

Comment: To put the same statement in yet another logically equivalent way, "anything that happens is not prohibited by the standard".  Or to take a specific instance of the universally quantified space, "If demons flew out my nose, it would not indicate the implementation is non-conforming."

Comment: “Anything that happens is not prohibited by the standard” is a different statement from “Anything can happen,” and they are not equivalent. The former is true (in the context of undefined behavior). The latter is false.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: That would be true of compilers that seek to process the language the authors of the Standard sought to describe.  When using clang or gcc with optimizations enabled, the fact that some particular action would invoke Undefined Behavior may arbitrarily disrupt the behavior of other actions that should have been independent.  In gcc. for example, computation of `(ushort1 * ushort2) & 0xFFFFu;` will be interpreted as an invitation to blindly assume within surrounding code `ushort1` won't exceed `0x7FFFFFFF/ushort2`.

Comment: @supercat: That comment has nothing to do with my prior comments; its topic is not under discussion in these comments.

Comment: @M.M: If some particular a source text T wouldn't exercise any of the translation limits given in 5.4.2.1, in what circumstances, if any, could s anything an otherwise-conforming implementation might do with T render it non-conforming?  If `T` were to exercise the translation limits, and an implementation didn't process any other source texts that did so in the fashion described by the Standard, failure to process `T` as described by the Standard would render that implementation non-conforming.  That's the only situation I can see where the Standard would impose any requirements at all.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: IMHO, students should be taught both that the Standard neither forbids nor invites nonsensical behavior, but that some compilers interpret the Standard's lack of a prohibition as an invitation.  I don't think students should be told that the Standard invites such behavior, but I think they need to be aware that some implementations behave as though it does anyway.  Do you disagree with the latter point?

Comment: @EricPostpischil "anything can happen" in this context means "Anything that happens is not prohibited by the standard" . You are taking the words of this common English language idiom too literally and out of context

Comment: @M.M: (a) The text contains other sentences showing that purported meaning is not correct, such as “your program no longer has any guarantees” (which is false; guarantees made by the hardware manufacturer still apply, specifications of the operating system still apply, et cetera). (b) Stack Overflow answers are intended to inform people who do not have the information, so they have not yet learned the purported context and do not have the information necessary to interpret the words to mean something different from what they say. (c) We repeatedly see this false statement on Stack Overflow…

Comment: … accompanied by statements showing it is meant literally, such as denials that any information can be gained from interpreting the results of undefined behavior (which is false because it is useful for debugging and occasionally provides insights for students into how compilers are constructed and operate, how operating systems operate, and more) or that anything can be relied on in the presence of “undefined behavior” (which is false because things other the language standard may provide definitions, and this is necessary in essentially all practical applications.)

Comment: @EricPostpischil “your program no longer has any guarantees” means “your program no longer has any guarantees provided by the standard”. The language is defined by the standard , any answers about the language definition are in the context of the standard unless otherwise specified.   Feel free to expand on things but you are wrong to take statements out of context and call them "false" .

Comment: "anything can happen" doesn't even have a literal meaning (if you disagree then I'd love to see your attempt at a definition.. can immovable objects and irresistible forces be created?) .  It only has idiomatic meaning  and one that is well understood by English speakers ; the meaning is similar to "expect the unexpected" .

Answer (score 1):

“Undefined” simply means that neither the compiler nor the execution environment are required to handle the situation in any particular way.  In general, UB is not predictable or consistent; once your program invokes undefined behavior, you’ve voided the warranty and all bets are off.

UB is kind of like Murphy’s Law - you can’t make it work in your favor.

There may be specific instances of UB that cancel each other out, but you can’t guarantee that they will for any particular build.  You’re better off fixing the code that caused the undefined behavior in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Undefined Behavior, as the C and C++ Standard uses the term, means nothing more nor less than that the Standards impose no requirements on how a conforming implementations behave when given input that would result in them attempting to perform a particular action.  The fact that a particular input would cause a program to invoke UB means that, from a standards-compliance standpoint, nothing an implementation could do would render it non-conforming, no matter what else the program does.

As to whether the behavior is predictable, that depends upon whether an implementation opts to define the behavior.  According to the authors of the C Standard, Undefined behavior among other things "It also identifies areas of possible conforming language extension: the implementor may augment the language by providing a definition of the officially undefined behavior."  Nearly all quality implementations can be configured to extend the semantics of the language in this fashion, though some may require completely disabling many optimizations in order to avoid having them break corner cases that a quality optimizer could have supported easily.

With regard to your particular question about multiple forms of UB that interact, implementations may specify that some particular action over which the Standard would impose no requirements will behave predictably when, and only when, it is preceded by some other action over which the Standard would impose no requirements.